# Jboss Fuse UnsupportedEncodingException iso88591

Tags: apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I can't access my jboss fuse 6.3 admin console, I've been receiving the following message:

```
unable to start shell because iso88591
```

In the data/log/fuse.log shows the below stack

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: iso88591
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(StreamEncoder.java:61)[:1.8.0_131]
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:100)[:1.8.0_131]
        at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:231)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.<init>(Console.java:111)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1.runConsole(ShellFactoryImpl.java:138)[156:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:126)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.JaasHelper.doAs(JaasHelper.java:47)[25:org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh.ShellFactoryImpl$ShellImpl$1.run(ShellFactoryImpl.java:124)[156:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
```

Comment: Are you setting a custom encoding somewhere, e.g., in the JVM configuration? "iso88591" is not an encoding name I recognize -- perhaps it should be "iso8859-1"?

Answer (score 1):

Encoding has to be `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`. You can find `LC_TYPE` by executing locale command. If `LC_CTYPE` is not set `env_US.UTF-8` you can update in bash_profile. I too faced the same issue in solaris. In my case `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"` then, I updated 
`LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` now its working fine.